# convert State integers to onehotvector

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a function that I use to convert two states into a one-hot vector and combine it all, and it works fine, but if I have a large `L`, for example, `3000`, it will take time. The function works like this with `L=3`.

```
def OH3(x,end=2,len=3):
  x = T.LongTensor([[x]])
  end = T.LongTensor([[end]])
  one_hot_x = T.FloatTensor(len,l)
  one_hot_end = T.FloatTensor(len,l)
  first=one_hot_x.zero_().scatter_(1,x,1)
  second=one_hot_end.zero_().scatter_(1,end,1)
  vector=T.cat((one_hot_x,one_hot_end),dim=1)
  return vector
```

the output:

```
OH3(1)
tensor([[0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

as I mentioned, the function works fine but slower for a large number of states, and I sent multiple states at once, like 500 states, it will take 4 second

Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: To clarify, `x` is the relevant class (an integer index that should be assigned a value of 1 in the final encoding), `end` is also an integer index that should be assigned a value of 1), and `len` is the length of the encoding, and the end encoding such that total vector length is `2*len`?

Comment: yes your assumptions are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided the assumptions made in the comments above are correct, this should be about as fast as you can get it done, one allocation of a new array and 2 assignment operations. Let me know if I'm missing something.

```
def OH3(x,end=2,len=3):
    vector = torch.zeros(2*len,dtype = int)
    vector[[x,len+end] = 1
    return vector
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
def HO3(x,end=2,len=3):
 start=[0]*3
 end=[0]*3

 list[x]=1
 end[end=1
 f=list+end
 tvalue=T.torch([f])
 return tvalue
```